# Why does radio button with ng-repeat not work?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've got a simple ng-repeat with a radio button which refuses to function. The following works perfectly fine:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="display_as"  name="display_as" value="1">position 1
    <input type="radio" ng-model="display_as"  name="display_as" value="2">position 2
</label>
<pre>{{ display_as }}</pre>
```

but with the following I do see two radio buttons (as expected) and I can select eitherone of the two radio buttons, but `$scope.display_as` remains undefined.

```
<label ng-repeat="position in user.positions" class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="display_as"  name="display_as" value="{{ $index }}">{{ position.name }}
</label>
<pre>{{ display_as }}</pre>
```

Why oh why?! Could anybody enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong in my `ng-repeat`?

Comment: for some mistery, if you to use user.display_as, it works (http://jsbin.com/yaseye/edit?html,js,output). Excelent @andrei-gheorghiu, in the past I had the same problem and I only got it using ng-change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a separate child `$scope` for each iteration through `user.positions`. None of those `$scope`s have a `display_as` property.

You can access the parent `$scope` inside an `ng-repeat` by using `$parent`. In your case: `$parent.display_as`.